# Can North American split-phase 220VAC supply power to a device designed for single phase power?

Tags: power, mains

In North America I know we use split-phase 220V power. I am wanting to purchase an industrial power supply that has an input rating 100-240VAC, and has 3 input terminals labeled ⏚, L, N. I know the N is for neutral, which would apply to most of the world which uses regular single-phase 220V. But can I plug split-phase power (with its two hots, 180 out of phase) into those two L, N terminals safely?

Comment: How many watts is this power supply?  If it is only a few hundred watts, I would just run it off L & N (110 VAC). Really high power devices should be run L - L (220 VAC) to keep the two legs balanced.

Comment: Its a mere 280W. I know supplying it with 110V is a sane option, but my question is more academic in nature. Although it would also save me from having to do any additional electrical wiring since there is already a 220V outlet where I need it. I am wiring a 220V VFD as well.

Comment: @SteveEasley In North America the very term *split-phase* ***means*** two hots (H1 and H2) and a neutral (N). That's why it is called split-phase -- to differentiate it from, for example, some EU countries that provide only single-phase 220. In North America, the N is also usually "grounded" using either a Ufer ground (20' of #4 bare copper or else 1/2" iron rebar in concrete) or else a fat, long copper stake in the ground near the home. Why do you imagine "no neutral" is implied by "split-phase" when exactly the opposite is the case?

Comment: @jonk I think you are reading more into my question than I am asking. I know neutral is used in the North American systems. But I have a shop full of 220V equipment that don't use that neutral. My question is concerning that exact thing.

Comment: @SteveEasley The way I read what you wrote made me think you believed exactly "otherwise." I'll let it drop. You can hook up a 220 single-phase device (so long as it works with 60 Hz, obviously) across H1 and H2 and the device will run (it may need to be isolated from "earth," though.) Whether or not it is SAFE for a human to touch is yet another question. Does the equipment ground its chassis to one side? (I don't know what standards were used for your equipment and can't guess about it.) But if so, you probably need to disconnect that first. You don't want any metal-work to be at H1 or H2.

Comment: @SteveEasley Bear in mind that I'm a hobbyist only and do NOT specialize, nor am I in any way licensed or otherwise qualified, in answering safety questions. So use your own head here.

Comment: @jonk I can see now my extra wording might be distracting, I may drop the "(two hots, no neutral)" part. Thanks for the answers. Especially for the grounding part. I can see it would be bad if what they call N on the input is grounded to the chassis. I will checking into that.

Comment: @SteveEasley Yeah, if N is grounded to any conductive surfaces you can touch then it would be "a very bad thing." If you have (and since I was confused by your wording I'm being cautious) H1 (L1), H2 (L2), and N in your shop but your equipment has only L and N, then you need to verify that N within the equipment doesn't connect to anything you might touch. Just use an Ohmmeter to test this. If it connects, find and remove the connection. You may also want to use your existing N to tie back to the chassis. But, again, this MAY or MAY NOT be a good idea depending on a lot of things.

Comment: The transformer uses L and N to simplify things. AC wiring doesn't necessarily need a side to it to function. Refer to this https://i.imgur.com/9ndjD8U.jpg  You simply connect one hot to L, the other to N. The earth ground connects to the GND. ⏚

Comment: Don't mix grounds and neutrals. Ground is for safety and should never have any current flowing in it. I think that only the manufacturer of the power supply can answer your question for sure. It will likely depend on the filtering on the 2 power inputs. I would guess that they are symmetrical ("N" input not treated specially), then both inputs could be "hot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: **220V is very dangerous!** Do not mess around without proper knowledge and safety procedures and equipment. Be sure to never wire things without being unplugged or with the breakers at off! Measure voltages at all times before wiring or touching power cables. If you aren't sure, call a professional electrician.

As for the question: the answer is yes, you can safely plug split-phase 220V into the L and N terminals safely. The ⏚ label indicates Ground, or Equipment Ground. This is usually a bare wire in 220V wiring.

By using this diagram as an example you can see why we call 110V with the labels Line and Neutral. There is 110V between any Line and the Neutral. There is 220V between any two Lines.

: [image]
(oempanels.com)

To wire your power supply, simply connect the two Lines (Hot) to the L and N respectively. ex. Line 1 (usually red) goes to the L label of the power supply. Line 2 (usually black) goes to the N label of the power supply. The ⏚ label indicates earth ground. This is usually the bare/green wire in the middle of a 220V cable, or the wire connected to the metal casing of a 220V electrical box.

ex:(copyright MS Paint)

[image]

Comment: That picture isn't correct it's got plug ground going to l/h2 and plugs l/h2 going to ground